# The Icon and Build Section Not Selected on the Selected Areas. How to Show It Again

Tags: android, ide

The Icon and Build Section Not Selected on the Selected Areas. How to Show It Again...Android Studio IDE.

[ANDROID STUDIO IDE SHOWING IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBICh.jpg)

[Now showing IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7uVg.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean: View -> Appearance -> Tool Window Bars? (Also switchable with the little icon in the lower-left: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2gGy.png.)

Comment: It's correct. Thank you so much, Mr.Mike